# Removing quotation marks from date in django template

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Please this is what I have ['2020-03-03', 35.83483379334211] but I wanted 
[2020-03-03, 35.83483379334211] in my Django template so I can render it in highchart js.Any help?

Comment: it appears in the source code like this [&#39;2020-03-03&#39;, 36.04693743400276], when I inspect. which denies the highchart to render

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to answer without you posting the code showing where you generate the list in the first place, but here are some general rules when rendering python lists into highcharts from Django.

- Always pass your list into the template as str(my_list)
- When supplementing into the highcharts js, add |safe to the end of the template context variable. (Example {name:"My Dataset", data:{{ my_list|safe }}})